# Question with scipy.optimize

Tags: python, scipy

I am a newbie and I need your help!!

I have installed scipy on my Ubuntu.

When I ran the code from scipy import optimize, special

I get the following in terminal:
 can't read /var/mail/scipy.optimize

and if I type python, and get >>> then type in from scipy import optimize

then I ran code including scipy, optimize, I get the following:
name 'scipy' is not defined

Comment: The first problem is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio; the second is simply that you have not installed `scipy`

Answer (score 3):

`from scipy import optimize, special` on the shell prompt starts the `from` command, which is an email program.

`from scipy import optimize, special` in Python will put the modules `optimize` and `special` in your namespace, but not `scipy`. Either use them unqualified or do `import scipy` instead.