# Python won't import time

Tags: python, import, xserver

Here's my file in full:

```
import time
```

When I run it, or any import statement, I get:

```
import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/366.
```

I'm running it from an ssh into a virtual machine running `Ubuntu 12.04.03`.
`python` is `v2.7`. When I run the script in the terminal with the `Ubuntu` UI, I get a cross hair mouse cursor like it wants a screen capture. When I click, the program ends.

Why would `import time` access some kind of UI feature?

The scripts I'm trying to write/run are basic text processing and number crunching command line tools. no UI features needed.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try just importing one function? For example, from time import time

Comment: Are you sure you're typing `import` at the *Python* interactive shell and not at the terminal shell prompt? I think you're running the http://linux.die.net/man/1/import command from a shell prompt. Or that your `.py` script doesn't have the right `#! /bin/env python` line at the start and isn't being run in Python

Comment: tried from time import time, got "from: can't read /var/mail/time"

Comment: looks like this was the problem: I wasn't running it through python. this answer cleared it up [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio)