# Python- error in importing rllab

Tags: python, anaconda

I installed rllab successfully:

```
$ source activate rllab3
(rllab3) $ Python 3.5.2 :: Continuum Analytics, Inc.
(rllab3)  $ import rllab
(rllab3)  $
```

but when I try to import other libraries:

```
(rllab3) $ from rllab.algos.trpo import TRPO
 from: can't read /var/mail/rllab.algos.trpo

 (rllab3) $ from rllab import rllab
 from: can't read /var/mail/rllab
```

I can understand why this happens.
I defined the environment variable

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/home/b**/rllab3"
```

when I am trying to load it from spyder:

```
[] import rllab
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<ipython-input-1-6bfd29d10263>", line 1, in <module>
import rllab
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rllab'
```

I can't figure the problem. If the problem is with environment variable, can anyone help me to fix it?
I can not find where were rllab is installed on my system (I installed it with anaconda)

Comment: can you check `python --version` ? you have installed `rllab3` for `python 3.5.2`

Comment: can you paste exact version ?

Comment: rllab3 on Python 3.6.2 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Sep 22 2017, 02:03:08) [GCC 7.2.0] on linux
with anaconda 3

Comment: are you using linux or macOS ? then open terminal type python and press `tab` on keyboard and you will see list of python interpreter installed. Here if you see python3.5 then select it and check if import works

Comment: I have not python 3.5, but python 3.6. is the the problem?

Comment: Yes `rllab3` is installed for `python 3.5.2` so it can not be access via 3.6

Comment: I used python 2.7, installed rllab 2 and successfully installed it. import rllab works but when I try: from rllab.algos.trpo import TRPO
the result is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<ipython-input-2-8a95286a7b9f>", line 1, in <module> from rllab.algos.trpo import TRPO  File "/home/bayes/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rllab-0.0.0-py2.7.egg/rllab/algos/trpo.py", line 1, in <module>
....

ImportError: No module named joblib.pool

Comment: The "can't read /var/mail/..." problem is a basic pilot error, and a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this thread is quite old, but I started working on rllab lately and this is my understanding. rllab3 is a conda envrionment similar to virtual environment, as mentioned in the [rllab documentation](http://rllab.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/installation.html#preparation). It doesn't have the actual modules installed within it, you'd need to install it seperately.

```
(rllab3) $ python3
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import rllab
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'rllab'
```

To use the package you need to have the actual package downloaded and the python path pointing to that package.

```
(rllab3) $ pwd
/Users/r**/***/repo/rllab
(rllab3) $ python3
Python 3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from rllab.algos.trpo import TRPO
>>>
```