# from: can't read /var/mail/docx

Tags: python

Im having a problem Running my Python Program due the from: can't read /var/mail/docx Error, I tried to execute this pip uninstall docx && pip install docx && from docx import Document but didn't work Sorry for bad Grammar.

Comment: Please share your code snippet in the description

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not finding your Python path or you're not using python command. Try running the script using python.

```
python script.py
```

Otherwise put the following line on top of your program:

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python
```