# NameError: name 'By' is not defined (selenium)

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error in my python code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Batch-image-compression/compress_pic.py", line 54, in <module>

**input_box = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//input[@class="_2zg9i"]')**

NameError: name 'By' is not defined
```

In my script I have:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common import By
```

The showing error :

> from: can't read /var/mail/selenium.webdriver.common

Comment: Have you checked the seleniuum installation logs? Looks like incorrect install of the library.

Comment: The second error seems unrelated, and is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio

Answer (score 16):

Use this line instead:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```