# How to fix error message "from: can't read /var/mail/pwn"

Tags: python, ubuntu, virtual-machine, pwntools

I am practicing Buffer Overflow exploits, and I am following this [website](https://medium.com/@two06/solving-a-simple-buffer-overflow-with-pwntools-575a37e4ddb1). My code looks like this:

```
# Run the program, waits until it sees ':' (end of prompt), send our format strings, then prints 
# the output. The last line ensures that we don't kill the process
#!/usr/bin/env python  


from pwn import *


io = process('./00')
print(io.recvregex(b':'))  # read untill we get the prompt

io.sendline(b'%p,%p,%p')
io.recvline()
print(io.recvline())

io.sendline(cyclic(50))  # pwntools cyclic generates a 50 char pattern to send as input
io.wait()

core = io.corefile  # pwntools pulls core dump to extract needed values
stack = core.rsp

info('rsp = %#x', stack)
pattern = core.read(stack, 4)
rip_offset = cyclic_find(pattern)

info('rip offset is %d', rip_offsett)
io.interactive()    # interactive() lets us communicate with the program through keyboard
```

Unfortunatley, I am unable to run it. This is the output I get:

```
m@m-VirtualBox:~/Documents$ ./pwn.py
from: can't read /var/mail/pwn
./pwn.py: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./pwn.py: line 7: `io = process('./00')'
```

I have tried looking at [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/372926/bash-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token) question for answers, but adding more quotation marks did not solve it, neither did adding the line `#!/usr/bin/env python` at the top of the .py-file (like they suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228364/how-to-solve-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16069816/getting-python-error-from-cant-read-var-mail-bio)) How do I fix this?

Comment: The solution is to add the "shebang" line (`#!/usr/bin/env python`).  Your script is being interpreted as a bash script, not a Python script.  If that didn't fix it, then you didn't do it correctly.  Note that the shebang line MUST BE THE FIRST LINE.  You might try typing `python pwn.py` to prove that.

Comment: As a second note, you cannot give your own file the same name as a standard module.  When you do `from pwn import *`, Python is going to use YOUR file instead of the module.  You need to change your file name.

Comment: I changed the name of my program, but I still get the same error...

Comment: Run the script with `python scriptname.py` rather than `./scriptname.py`

Comment: "Top" means "first line". If you put the shebang anywhere else, it won't work.

Comment: Right.  The first line BEFORE any comments.  The first two characters in the file must be `'#'` and `'!'`.  That's what the Linux kernel looks for to figure out what program runs this file.